# INNER JOIN não retorna resultado do banco

Tags: mysql, sql-select, query

Estou a tentar usar este código:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tb_trabalhador
INNER JOIN tb_detalhe_trabalhador ON Tb_trabalhador.id = tb_detalhe_trabalhador.tb_trabalhador_id
```

E ele retorna o resultado em branco.

Será que há forma de contornar isso com outro código?

tb_detalhe_trabalhador:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tb_trabalhador_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tb_funcoes_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MedicaValidade` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MedicaAnexo` longblob,
   (...)
```

tb_trabalhador:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Nome` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`Morada` text,
`Tipo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
(...)
```

Comment: A tua consulta está em condições, se nenhum resultado é devolvido é porque não existe nenhum ID para fazer a relação. Já verificaste se existem registos relacionados por esse campo?

Comment: Direto no banco essa consulta retorna alguma linha?

Comment: o meu teste é feito no Banco antes de ser colocado no codigo php. O resultado é em branco

Comment: Poste a estrutura das duas tabelas envolvidas, fica mais fácil para ajudar. Tem certeza que a tabela  tb_detalhe_trabalhador tem um campo de nome tb_trabalhador_id ?

Comment: Alterei agora o código com a estrutura da tabela

Comment: Coloque um print do resultado do seu banco de dados. A unica coisa é que pode não existir relação entre as tabelas.

Comment: Com base nos comentários na minha resposta, o teu problema parece ser outro relacionado com a inserção de dados e não a recolha dos mesmos. Sugiro que abras uma nova pergunta para lidar com esse assunto.

Comment: Duas perguntas: 1. existem dados em `tb_detalhe_trabalhador`? e 2. a chave estrangeira está corretamente configurada?

Answer (score 4):

A sintaxe do seu Join está aparentemente correta.

O que resta você verificar, é se ao inserir os detalhes do trabalhador, se o valor do `tb_trabalhador.id` desejado está sendo incluido no `tb_detalhe_trabalhador.tb_trabalhador_id`, para que a relação se complete, visto que a condição é justamente esta:

```sql
tb_trabalhador.id = tb_detalhe_trabalhador.tb_trabalhador_id
```

Para obter o ID correto, caso você esteja inserindo um novo trabalhador e seus detalhes na mesma série de operações, uma possibilidade é utilizar a função [`LAST_INSERT_ID( )`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)<sup>(en)</sup> logo após inserir o trabalhador, e em seguida inserir os detalhes com o ID retornado pela função.

Aproveitando, veja **[esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)** sobre *joins*, e note os IDs das tabelas exemplo e os resultados caso a condição do `ON`seja satisfeita ou não.

Answer (score 2):

## Actualização

Após conversa tida nos comentários desta resposta, ficou claro que a tua consulta não está a devolver resultados pois ao procederes à inserção dos registos na base de dados não estás a aplicar ao campo `tb_trabalhador_id` da tua tabela `tb_detalhe_trabalhador` o valor que ficou registado no campo `id` da tua tabela `tb_trabalhador`.

Com a excepção do erro de digitação no nome da tabela que mencionei na "resposta original", a tua consulta está bem construída e só não devolve resultados se efectivamente não existirem resultados relacionados pelos campos indicados na mesma.

---

## Resposta Original

A tua consulta está em condições e bem formatada, mas penso que tens um erro de digitação no nome da tabela:

```
Tb_trabalhador
```

Deveria ser com `t` minúsculo:

```
tb_trabalhador
```

<sup>Ou vice-versa.</sup>

#### Consulta:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_trabalhador
INNER JOIN tb_detalhe_trabalhador ON tb_trabalhador.id = tb_detalhe_trabalhador.tb_trabalhador_id
```

---

[9.2.2 Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names. This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive. However, Mac OS X also supports UFS volumes, which are case sensitive just as on any Unix.

Que traduzido:

> No MySQL, as base-de-dados correspondem às directorias dentro da directoria de dados. Cada tabela dentro de uma base-de-dados corresponde a pelo menos um arquivo na directoria da base-de-dados (e possivelmente mais, dependendo do mecanismo de armazenamento). Consequentemente, a sensibilidade a letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas por parte do sistema operativo subjacente desempenha um papel na sensibilidade de letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas nos nomes das base-de-dados e tabelas. Isto significa que os nomes das base-de-dados e tabelas não são sensíveis a letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas no Windows, mas são na maioria das variedades de Unix. Uma excepção notável é o Mac OS X, que é baseado em Unix, mas utiliza um tipo de sistema de arquivos padrão (HFS +), que não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas. No entanto, o Mac OS X também suporta volumes UFS, que são sensíveis, assim como em qualquer Unix.

Comment: Erro meu ao colocar o código aqui. Pois onde testei tem tudo letras minúsculas.

Comment: Só mesmo se não existirem registos relacionados, de resto está tudo bem com a tua consulta.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta e deixei a estrutura das tabelas. 
Só uma questão. Quando eu insiro os dados na BD na tabela tb_trabalhador_id digo que ele é NULL?

Comment: O teu campo `tb_trabalhador_id` da tabela `tb_detalhe_trabalhador` tem que conter o valor do campo `id` da tua tabela `trabalhador`. Caso contrário a tua consulta não vai devolver resultados pois estás a procurar por uma relação que não existe.

Comment: Claro que não. Se você está inserindo detalhes do trabalhador significa que você já sabe qual é o trabalhador, então você já tem o ID (ou deveria te-lo). Se você está tentando criar o registro do trabalhador já com os detalhes você pode inserir o trabalhador, recuperar o id gerado pelo BD e inserir o detalhe na mesma query.

Comment: O teu problema parece ser outro relacionado com a inserção de dados e não na recolha dos mesmos. Sugiro que abras uma nova pergunta para lidar com esse assunto.